# Extract a specific node from an XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, node.js, xpath

I want to extract only the body node/tag from an XML file using doc.xpath in Ruby

The node to extract from the XML file:

```
<wcm:element name="Body">&lt;p&gt;A new study suggests that &lt;a href="ssNODELINK/SmokingAndCancer"&gt;tobacco&lt;/a&gt; companies may be using online video portals, such as YouTube, to get around advertising restrictions and market their products to young people.&lt;/p&gt;
</wcm:element>
```

I have tried the following:

```
page_content = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element").inner_text
```

But this extracts every node everything

Then I tried this:

```
page_content = doc.xpath("/wcm:root/wcm:element/Body")
```

But does not work.

Anyone has any suggestions how to extract exactly the body section of an XML file using doc.xpath in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain I've understood what you mean but… let's not let that stop us. You want to get the content of a particular node from the input. Your first XPath statement:

```
/wcm:root/wcm:element
```

is extracting every element with name `wcm:element` that is a child of the `wcm:root` element which is the root element.

Your second:

```
/wcm:root/wcm:element/Body
```

is similar but looks for elements with name `Body` which are children of the `wcm:element`.

What you need to is to get the values of the `wcm:element` element where the attribute `name` is set to the value `Body`. You access attributes in XPath by prefixing them with an `@` sign and to express a *where* condition you use `[...]` - a predicate. You XPath statement needs to be:

```
/wcm:root/wcm:element[@name = 'Body']
```

I'm assuming that your XPath execution environment is fine the namespace prefixes (wcm) because you say that your first query returned content.

Comment: Are the `wcm:element` elements direct children of the `wcm:root` element? If not try `/wcm:root//wcm:element[@name = 'Body']`. The `//` means that XPath follows the descendant axis and looks down the document tree to any level. If you can, how about posting more of the XML? Additionally, you may need to declare the namespaces you are using.